# ValueError no KFold do Scikit-learn: o meu dataset tem duas classes! O que está acontecendo?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, sklearn

Tentei fazer uma validação cruzada com uma regressão logística usando o *Scikit-learn* . Segue o código:

```
 kf = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
    kf.get_n_splits(previsores)
    for train_index, test_index in kf.split(previsores):

        X_train, X_test = previsores[train_index], previsores[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = classe[train_index], classe[test_index]

        logmodel.fit(X_train, y_train)
        print (confusion_matrix(y_test, logmodel.predict(X_test)))


        lista_matrizes.append(confusion_matrix(y_test, logmodel.predict(X_test)))
    #print(f" Matriz de Confusão Média \n{np.mean(lista_matrizes, axis=0)}")
    print("Matriz de Confusão Média")
    print(np.mean(lista_matrizes, axis=0))
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
ValueError: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: 1
```

O meu dataset tem duas classes (0 e 1) mas recebo o erro acima. O que fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Isso pode acontecer devido ao fato de uma dos folders do k-folder ter pegado amostras de apenas uma classe.
Da uma olhada no tamanha do seu dataset e no tamanho dos folders.
de uma olhada se é possivel que um folder pegue apenas uma classe.

Comment: Como eu posso verificar se "um folder pegue apenas uma classe."? Poderia detalhar mais?